# Toyota Prado V6 gasoline engine component enquiry

Tags: engine, toyota, troubleshooting, gasoline, prado

[image]

Which component sits in the circled area and what is it's function?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is the Prado in question? And I'm not sure if this is the diesel or petrol version?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it say gasoline in the header of the question so it is not a diesel.to the op please post some more details.